# Javascript JSON stringify emptying my array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send array to the server side by stringyfing it but after the operation the result is empty `[]`. There is my code:

```
let calculatePriceOfMultipleFields = (model, field, select, computable) => {
        if(computable.length === 0){
            return false
        }
        let priceArray = fillPriceArray(model, computable)
        console.log(priceArray)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(priceArray))
        let ajaxData = {
            id: select.value,
            model: model,
            field: field,
            priceArray: priceArray
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/erp/currencyhandler/multiple-currency-handler/get-price-by-currency",
            data: ajaxData,
            success: function ( data ) {

                console.log(data)
                return false
            }
        })
    }

    let fillPriceArray = (model, computable) => {
        let price = []
        computable.forEach((name) => {
            let id = model.toLowerCase()+"-"+name
            let input = document.getElementById(id)
            price[id] = input.value
        })
        return price
    }
```

What I get from the `console.log` is:

```
[crmorder-amount: "6.22", crmorder-delivery_price: "5", crmorder-discount_percentage: "15", crmorder-total_amount: "10.29"]
```

On the first one where the array is filled up and the second one is simply `[]`.
What is wrong with my stringyfing and where is my mistake ? Thank you!

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` only looks at numeric property names of an array. Your code is using an array (`[ ]`) but it's using strings for the property names.

Comment: If you initialize `price` to `{ }` instead it may work a lot better.

Comment: Well didn't know about that. Thank you very much! Learned something new today :)

Comment: @Pointy for a start, it *works*.

Comment: You are using Object key/value syntax in an Array container.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! All good now :)